# Solve a memoization in Haskell

Tags: haskell, memoization

I wrote data type and instance Monad class. Below is my source code:

```
data UI a = UI { unUI :: a } 
             deriving Functor


instance Applicative UI where
    pure   = UI
    m *>  k = m >>= \ _ -> k
    m <*  k = m >>= \ _ -> m
    m <*> k = UI $ (unUI m) (unUI k)


instance Monad UI where
    m >>  k = m >>= \ _ -> k
    m >>= k = k $ unUI m
    return  = UI
```

But, when i use function like below:

```
generateUUID :: UI String
generateUUID = do 
    ruuid <- liftIO $ UV4.nextRandom
    return $ UV.toString ruuid
```

I encounter problems with memoization!
Is it poosible to do something?

Comment: And for MonadIO `instance MonadIO UI where
   liftIO a = return $ unsafePerformIO a`

Comment: how do you expect memoization to cope with statefulness of `IO` actions?

Comment: There are no guarantees about what happens if one abuses of `unsafePerformIO`: that's why it is unsafe! That can only be used safely when you don't care when or if the IO is fired. Why don't you use the `IO` monad directly, instead? You can even wrap it, if you want as `newtype UI a = UI { unUI :: IO a }` and define your instances around that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using `unsafePerformIO` to hide the presence of effects in `IO` actions you are deliberately (and most probably illegally) entering the realm of pure functions. In that realm it is allowed to memoize / refactor. The compiler will usually try to use the purity to full extent to avoid redundant work in runtime. Is there a real reason why you would hide the impurity, especially in something called `UI`, where one can expect interaction with outside world (human)? This could indicate bad design. Your `UI` seems to be the same as `Identity` which is the simplest functor without any impure effects.